# Why data is not bound to label in my WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am doing a simple `DataBinding` application in `WPF`. In this app whatever I type in a `TextBox` named `txtName`, should appear in the `Label`. For this purpose I used binding in `WPF`, but its not getting bound.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="315*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="188*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="79,12,0,0" Name="txtName"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="22,12,0,0" Name="label1"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"
             Content="Name"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="79,56,0,0" Name="txtSirName"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="SirName" Height="28"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,56,0,0"
           Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" />
    
    <!-- Following is the label which I bound -->

    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=txtName,Path=text}"
           Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,112,0,0"
           Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
</Grid>
```

I am new to `WPF`. Please guide me.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, the `Path` is the default Binding property, so if you'd like, you could also write `{Binding Text, ElementName=txtName}` (meaning `Path` is implicit).

Comment: ohh, thanks @Default , the link through which i learnt contained this one, so i used this. But thanx for new information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty sure XAML is case sensitive. Your binding path is `text` when it should be `Text`.

Comment: Thanks I was unaware of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

TextBox has property Text, not text. Small mistake :)

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="315*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="188*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,12,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Content="Name"/>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,56,0,0" Name="txtSirName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="SirName" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,56,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" />
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=txtName,Path=Text}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,112,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I was not aware about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Path=***T***ext

It's a typo problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtName}, Path=text}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,112,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
```

Comment: "service provider is missing INamesolver service" this is the error in tooltip.

Comment: Why use `Source={}` when you have `ElementName`?

Comment: @Default I dont understood the this code. It given me above error[First comment]. What can it be?

Comment: @Freelancer My question was not directed at you. I believe your code is correct since you are using `ElementName`. I'd like Ahmed to explain why you should use `Source` instead because I do not understand why.

Comment: @Default see this http://dismantledtech.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/binding-with-elementname-cant-find-referenced-control/